# How to find the length of a 2D game object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I'd like an answer for the absolute beginner in how to find a length/height of a 2D game object using Unity. I'm trying to figure out whether or not a player clicked on the object, like so:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LoadNewGame : MonoBehaviour {
    //Objects
    Touch t;
    GameObject g;
    //Coords
    int touchX;
    int touchY;
    int objectX;
    int objectY;
    //Size
    //int sizex
    //int sizey

    //Initialization
    void Start () {
        //Touch
        t = Input.GetTouch;

        //Object Position
        objectX = g.transform.position.x;
        objectY = g.transform.position.y;
        //initialize sizex and sizey
    }

    //Clickity Click Click
    void Update () {
        touchX = t.position.x;
        touchY = t.position.y;
        //If the player clicked on the object
        if(touchX <= objectX && 
           touchY <= objectY &&
           //touchX => objectX + sizeX &&
           //touchY => objectY + sizeY
           ){
            //Do Stuff
        }


    }
}
```

Regardless of whether or not theres an easier way to find if they touched the image (tell me though), I'd like to know how to figure out the height and length of an object if it comes up again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you can do is shoot a ray in the scene from based on the mouse co-ordinates, this will then report any objects that the ray has collided with

Try this:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

if(hit.collider != null)
{

    Debug.Log ("Target Position: " + hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position);

}
```

[Reference](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/211708-Unity-2D-Raycast-from-mouse-to-screen)

Comment: also as a side note you should post these types of questions on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ you will get much better answers there